# Speeding up Python 'for' Loop with nested 'if' Statements

Tags: python, performance, list, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to speed up this loop I'm running to separate data into 2 categories. Normally I wouldn't care all that much about speed, but I am finding that right now the speed of this code is actually slowing down dramatically after multiple iterations. Here is how I wrote the code:

```
plane1Data = []
plane2Data = []
plane1Times = []
plane2Times = []
plane1Dets = []
plane2Dets = []
t1 = time.time()
for i in range(0,len(adcBoardVals)):#10000):
    tic = time.time()
    if adcBoardVals[i] == 5:
        if adcChannel[i] == 0:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [0]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [0]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 1:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [1]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [1]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 2:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [2]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [2]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 3:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [3]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [3]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 4:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [4]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            #plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [4]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 5:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [5]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [5]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 6:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [6]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [6]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 7:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [7]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [7]
    elif adcBoardVals[i] == 7:
        if adcChannel[i] == 0:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [16]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [16]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 1:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [17]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [17]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 2:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [18]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [18]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 3:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [19]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [19]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 4:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [20]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [20]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 5:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [21]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [21]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 6:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [22]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [22]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 7:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [23]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [23]
    elif adcBoardVals[i] == 6:
        if adcChannel[i] == 0:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [8]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [8]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 1:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [9]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [9]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 2:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [10]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [10]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 3:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [11]
            plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane1Times = plane1Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane1Dets = plane1Dets + [11]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 4:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [12]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [12]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 5:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [13]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [13]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 6:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [14]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [14]
        elif adcChannel[i] == 7:
            #detectorVal = detectorVal + [15]
            plane2Data = plane2Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
            plane2Times = plane2Times + [timeVals[i]]
            plane2Dets = plane2Dets + [15]
    if i%100000 == 0:
        print('k = ',i)   
        toc = time.time()
        print('tictoc = ',toc-tic)
        print('elapsed = ',toc-t1)
    elif i>900000:
        if i%1000 == 0:
            print('k = ',i)
            toc = time.time()
            print('tictoc = ',toc-tic)
            print('elapsed = ',toc-t1)

#detectorVal = np.array(detectorVal,dtype='float')
plane1Data = np.array(plane1Data,dtype='float')
plane2Data = np.array(plane2Data,dtype='float')
plane1Times = np.array(plane1Times,dtype='float')
plane2Times = np.array(plane2Times,dtype='float')
plane1Dets = np.array(plane1Dets,dtype='int')
plane2Dets = np.array(plane2Dets,dtype='int')
```

I vaguely remember from a c++ course I took a while ago that you can make lists that can run faster than nested 'if' statements. Is this correct and if so can I do this in python? I am running python 3.5 right now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This question may belong on the [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: 1) Use `append` instead of `+`, which is much slower, to add elements to a list. 2) If you are going to create NumPy arrays anyway, consider preallocating them (e.g. with [`np.empty`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html)) first and the setting the values in the loop.

Comment: 1) When I use the append function, the first value is always set to 'None' for some reason. I'm using, for instance, 

plane2Data = np.append(plane2Data,rawDataMat[i,:]) 

2) can I use np.empty to generate an array of unknown length? Thanks.

Comment: @jdehesa is spot-on on both counts. If you'll be using numpy, you could use its high-performance data structures instead of ordinary lists-- it _might_ speed things up a little bit, but this is unrelated to your real performance problem, which is the list copies.

Comment: Independently, you can greatly simplify your code by using the value of `adcChannel[i]` in the last assignment-- you'll be able to drop the entire set of embedded `if-else` blocks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem, and it is a **major** time waster, are the statements of the form

```
list_variable = list_variable + [ new_value ]
```

You call three of them on each loop iteration, e.g.:

```
plane1Data = plane1Data + [rawDataMat[i,:]]
```

Because you might have additional references to the list pointed to by `list_variable`, Python constructs a complete copy of the list on each call, only to discard the original when the assignment is carried out. Use the following form for all your list extensions, and you'll see astronomical improvement:

```
list_variable += [ new_value ]
```

Here's the proof that this really happens:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> x=list(range(100000))
>>> timeit("x += [99]", "from __main__ import x", number=1000)
0.00023529794998466969
>>> x=list(range(100000))
>>> timeit("x = x + [99]", "from __main__ import x", number=1000)
0.7576854809885845
>>> 0.7576854809885845 / 0.00023529794998466969
3220.110846855868
```

There you have it. For this 100000-element list, appending in place is more than ***three thousand times*** faster than copy-and-assign. You can profile a subset of your own data if you want to measure your gains.

Comment: Would this method of using 'x += [value]' be faster than using the 'x = np.append(x,[value])' method? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know-- measure it.

Comment: My guess, is, either method is plenty fast enough. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Hi Alexis, I did a check and using += is about 100 times faster than using np.append().

Comment: Good to know. To be fair, @jdehesa's suggestion was not that you use `np.append()`, but that you allocate a numpy array of the needed size (say, with all zeros) and then assign values to pre-allocated cells. But if you have adequate performance now, you should move on to more important things.

Comment: Hi Alexis. Do you have any idea how to help me with nested for loops?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969870/removing-nested-for-loop-to-find-coincidence-values?noredirect=1#comment78899301_45969870

Comment: Your other question is not about nested loops, but about doing better than dumb search with long lists. I'd suggest sorting and/or collecting the plane2 data into bins of 10k seconds, so that you only have to search for nearby planes in 2 bins. Maybe i'll post an answer later...