# Removing nested for loop to find coincidence values

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop

I am currently using a nested for loop to iterate through to arrays to find values that match a certain criterion. The problem is that this method is incredibly inefficient and time consuming. I was told that a better way might be to sort the two arrays based on the data, but this requires me to combine several 1D arrays and one multi-D array, sort based on one column, then separate them again. Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Here is a sample of my code:

```
x1 = []
x2 = []
velocity = []
plane1Times = np.array([[2293902],[2848853],[482957]])
plane2Times = np.array([[7416504],[2613113],[2326542]])
plane1Local = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,u,0],[0,2*u,0],[u,0,0],[u,u,0],[u,2*u,0],[2*u,0,0],[2*u,u,0],[2*u,2*u,0],[3*u,0,0],[3*u,u,0],[3*u,2*u,0]],dtype='float')
plane2Local = np.array([[0,0,D],[0,u,D],[0,2*u,D],[u,0,D],[u,u,D],[u,2*u,D],[2*u,0,D],[2*u,u,D],[2*u,2*u,D],[3*u,0,D],[3*u,u,D],[3*u,2*u,D]],dtype='float')
for i in range(0,len(plane1Times)):
    tic = time.time()
    for n in range(0,len(plane2Times)):
        if plane2Times[n] - plane1Times[i] <= 10000 and plane2Times[n] - plane1Times[i] > 0:
            x1 = plane1Local[plane1Dets[i]]
            x2 = plane2Local[plane2DetScale[n]]
            distance = np.sqrt((x2[0]-x1[0])**2 + (x2[1]-x1[1])**2 + (x2[2])**2)
            timeSeparation = (plane2Times[n]-plane1Times[i])*timeScale
            velocity += distance/timeSeparation
            break
```

To give you an example of the time it is currently taking, each array of times is 10**6 values long so 100 loops in `i` takes about 60 seconds. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you share the contents of your arrays ?

Comment: Each array is a 1D array with length = 10^6.

Comment: the variables plane1Dets and plane2DetScale are 1x10^6 arrays with values ranging from 0 to 11.

Comment: I suggest you check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post your question again. You'll have a better chance of getting a good solid answer if you make it easier for people to run / debug your problem

Comment: '<do stuff here>' better to give run-able code..

Comment: I updated what I wrote to make it runnable and included some of the timestamps that can be expected. Like I said above, these arrays are 10^6 values in length so I can't add all values.

Comment: This code sample is still missing information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant really test because the code you provided isn't complete, but this is a possible solution

```
for index,value in enumerate(plane1Times):
    vec = plane2Times - value
    row,col = np.where((vec<=10000)&(vec>0))
    if len(row) > 0:
        x1 = plane1Local[plane1Dets[index]]
        x2 = plane2Local[plane2DetScale[row[0]]]
        distance = np.sqrt((x2[0] - x1[0]) ** 2 + (x2[1] - x1[1]) ** 2 + (x2[2]) ** 2)
        timeSeparation = (plane2Times[row[0]] - plane1Times[index]) * timeScale
        velocity += distance / timeSeparation
```

Eliminate the second loop, and just do the subtraction all at once. Then search the new array, where it meats your criteria. Since it seems that you want the first value, just take the first index like `row[0]` to get the index of the value check. Removing the second for loop should drop the time considerably.